# Attempt to fetch logical page in database 2 failed. It belongs to allocation unit X not to Y

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Started to get following error when executing certain SP. Code related to this error is pretty simple, joining #temp table to real table

Full text of error:

```
Msg 605, Level 21, State 3, Procedure spSSRSRPTIncorrectRevenue, Line 123
Attempt to fetch logical page (1:558552) in database 2 failed. It belongs to allocation unit 2089673263876079616 not to 4179358581172469760.
```

Here is what I found:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2015739

This suggests some kind of issue with database. I run `DBCC CHECKDB` on user database and on temp database - all passes.

Second thing I'm doing - trying to find which table those allocation units belong

```
SELECT au.allocation_unit_id, OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS table_name, fg.name AS filegroup_name,
au.type_desc AS allocation_type, au.data_pages, partition_number
FROM sys.allocation_units AS au
JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON au.container_id = p.partition_id
JOIN sys.filegroups AS fg ON fg.data_space_id = au.data_space_id
WHERE au.allocation_unit_id in(2089673263876079616, 4179358581172469760)
ORDER BY au.allocation_unit_id
```

This returns 2 objects in `tempdb`, not in user db. So, it makes me think it's some kind of data corruption in tempdb? I'm developer, not DBA. Any suggestions on what I should check next?

Also, when I run query above, how can I tell REAL object name that I understand? Like `#myTempTable______...` instead of `#07C650CE`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by clearing the SQL caches:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
```

Apparently restarting the SQL service would have had the same affect.

(via [Made By SQL](http://madebysql.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/attempt-to-fetch-logical-page-in.html), reproduced here to help others!)

Answer (score 1):

I have like your get errors too.
firstly you must backing up to table or object for dont panic more after. I tryed below steps on my Database.

**step 1:**
Backing up table (data movement to other table as manuel or vs..how can you do)
I used to below codes to my table move other table

--CODE-

```
set nocount on;
DECLARE @Counter INT = 1;
DECLARE @LastRecord INT = 10000000; --your table_count

 WHILE @Counter < @LastRecord 
BEGIN 
BEGIN TRY  
    BEGIN
        insert into your_table_new SELECT * FROM your_table  WHERE your_column= @Counter --dont forget! create your_table_new before
    END 
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH    
     BEGIN
        insert into error_code select @Counter,'error_number' --dont forget the create error_code table before.
     END
 END CATCH
SET @Counter += 1;
END;
```

**step 2:**

```
-DBCC CHECKTABLE(your_table , REPAIR_REBUILD )
 GO
```

check your table. if you have an error go to other step_3.

**step 3:**
!!attention!! you can lost some data/datas on your table. but dont worry. so you backed-up your table in step_1.

```
-DBCC CHECKTABLE(your_table , REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
GO
```

Good luck!
~~pektas

Answer (score 0):

> In my case, truncating and re-populating data in the concerned **tables** was the solution.

Most probably the data inside tables was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Database ID 2 means your tempdb is corrupted. Fixing tempdp is easy. Restart sqlserver service and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an instance of a bug Microsoft fixed on SQL Server 2008 with queries on temporary tables that self reference (for example we have experienced it when loading data from a real table to a temporary table while filtering any rows we already have populated in the temp table in a previous step).

It seems that it only happens on temporary tables with no identity/primary key, so a workaround is to add one, although if you patch CU3 or later you also can enable the hotfix via turning a trace flag on.

For more details on the bug/fixes: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/960770/fix-you-receive-error-605-and-error-824-when-you-run-a-query-that-inse